# Adding active_admin_comments method in View file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller, view, comments, activeadmin

Is is possible to add active_admin_comments method in a view file?
Also,i tried this way too but it doesn't save the comments.

```
     <%= f.inputs "" do %>
     <% f.has_many :comments do  |c|  %>
        <% c.input :_destroy, :as => :boolean, :label => "Remove comment"     
        unless c.object.nil? or c.object.id.nil? %>

        <% c.input :author_id, :as => :hidden, :input_html => { :value => current_admin_user.id }    %>
        <% c.input :author_type, :as => :hidden, :input_html => { :value => current_admin_user.class.name } %>

        <% c.input :body, :label => false, :input_html => { :class => 'autogrow', :rows => 10, :cols => 20  }, :validate => { :presence => true } %>

    <% end %>

<% end %>
```

So what do you recommend me to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MVC pattern was developed to separate representation of information and data management.

Why don't you move your method to controller or model?